# Foreign key referencing unique composite key or single primary key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, unique-key

I am creating a database for an app that helps learn a language. I need to create tests that vary by section (test for grammar, about text, etc), topic and level.

```
USER
id (pk, autoincrement)
name
last_name
email (unique)
level_id
password

LEVEL
id (pk)
description

SECTION_TYPE
id (pk, no autoinc [to avoid creating a field for level_num])
section_name

TOPIC
?id (pk)
  section_id (fk)
  level_id (fk)
name

TEST
?id (pk)
  topic_id (fk)
  num

QUESTION
?id (pk)
  test_id (fk)
  num
text
has_multi_ans

ANSWER
?id (pk)
  question_id (fk)
  num
text
is_correct
```

I have read that using a composite index can facilitate fast search. And searching test by level and topic will be a frequent thing. But in my case a composite index is a unique combination.

I could make it a composite primary key with fields highlighted with tabs instead of creating single primary key `id`. Because in the first case I will have to also create composite foreign key. That would almost eliminate the need to create table test, but would be messy.

How should I go about this?

[Postgres FK referencing composite PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984022/postgres-fk-referencing-composite-pk) is a bit different since there are many other dependent fields so a unique single primary key is justified.

Comment: Please: Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `topic`, the case is simple, provided that the combination of `section_id` and `level_id` is to be unique. You can use that combination as your primary key, and you don't need a separate artificial primary key. That will save space and improve performance, because it avoids an additional column and index.

The case of `question` and `test` is less clear, because your proposed primary key includes an unspecified column `num`. I suppose it is some kind of a counter. Sure, if you store that counter in the table and if it is unique per foreign key value, your proposed primary key makes sense. If you generate `num` with a sequence, great. If that is supposed to be something else, like a "gap-less counter", I recommend that you reconsider the design carefully.